# Extending holomorphic forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\pi:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ a log resolution with (reduced) exceptional divisor $E$. Let $U$ be the smooth locus of $X$ and $\omega$ a holomorphic 1-form on $U$, when is it possible to extend $\omega$ to a holomorphic form on $\tilde{X}$ with at most logarithmic poles along $E$? In other words, when is $\pi_* \Omega^1_\tilde{X}(\log E)$ reflexive? Also can someone share any examples where such extension fails? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take a look at this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3243.pdf ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a result which is sort of what you are asking:

> **Theorem** (Greb-Kebekus-Kovács-Peternell)
>   Let $X$ be a complex quasi-projective variety of dimension $n$
>   and let $D$ be a $\mathbb Q$-divisor on $X$ such that the pair
>   $(X, D)$ is log canonical. Let $\pi:\widetilde X\to X$ be a log resolution
>   with $\pi$-exceptional set $E$ and $\widetilde D :=$ largest
>   reduced divisor contained in $\mathrm{supp}\ \pi^{−1}$(non-klt
>   locus), where the non-klt locus is the smallest closed subset
>   $W\subset X$ such that $(X\setminus W, D\setminus W)$ is klt.  Then the
>   sheaves $\pi^*\Omega_ X ^p(\log \widetilde D)$ are reflexive, for
>   all $p\leq n$.

This is proved in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10240-011-0036-0). A weaker version was proved in [this](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=7089264&fileId=S0010437X09004321) one.

For examples when this fails see 6.3 of the [older](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=7089264&fileId=S0010437X09004321) paper and 3.B, especially 3.2 of the [newer](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10240-011-0036-0) one. For an example when an extension like this fails for symmetric tensors see 3.1.3 of the [old](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=7089264&fileId=S0010437X09004321) paper.

For $1$-forms, as in your question there is a stronger result in [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-19/27.html) paper:

> **Theorem** (Graf-Kovács)
>     Let $(X, D)$ be a complex log canonical pair, and let $\pi\!: \widetilde X \to X$ be a log  resolution of $(X, D)$.  Then the sheaf
>     $
>   \pi_* \Omega_{\widetilde X}^1(\log \widetilde D) 
>   $ 
>     is reflexive, where $\widetilde D$ is any reduced divisor such that
>     $$\mathrm{Exc}(\pi) \wedge \pi^{-1}(\lfloor D\rfloor)
>   \subseteq \mathrm{supp} \widetilde D \subseteq
>   \pi^{-1}(\lfloor D\rfloor). $$

There is also an example in 7.4 of the [last](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-19/27.html) paper mentioned showing that this stronger statement fails for $p>1$.

Comment: Thanks Kovács, this answer is really helpful. By the way do you think log canonical singularity is the natural setting for extendability of 1-forms? Since I have also seen a result of Flenner (mentioned in your paper) that if codim(Sing X)>2 then the extension of 1-forms also exists.

Comment: For $p=\dim X$, the extendibility is almost the same as being lc. That suggests that lc is a natural class. Having said that I am not claiming that for $1$-forms it cannot hold in more generality. After all our paper with Graf is saying that for $1$-forms there is a stronger extension theorem than for forms with $p>1$. Then again, I would expect it to be relatively easy to find examples that are worse than log-canonical where it fails even for $1$-forms. The difficulty in going beyond the lc case is that I don't see a natural class of singularities where it would hold.